# k-center algorithm in one-dimensional space

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

I'm aware of the general k-center approximation algorithm, but my professor (**this is a question from a CS class**) says that in a one-dimensional space, the problem can be solved (optimal solution found, not an approximation) in `O(n^2)` polynomial time without depending on `k` or using dynamic programming.

As you might expect, I can't figure out how this is possible. The part currently causing me problems is how the runtime can not rely on `k`.

The nature of the problem causes me to try to step through the nodes on a sort of number line and try to find points to put boundaries, marking off the edges of each cluster that way. But this would require a runtime based on `k`.

The `O(n^2)` runtime though makes me think it might involve filling out an `nxn` array with the distance between two nodes in each entry.

Any explanation on how this is works or tips on how to figure it out would be very helpful.

Comment: So you just want...a general explanation of how k-center approximation works in one dimension?

Comment: No, I'm already aware of how the approximation works. My question is that, apparently in one-dimensional space, you can solve for the optimal solution (not an approx) in polynomial time. I'm asking how this is possible.

Comment: This is sort of a cs.stackexchange.com thing...

Comment: Is there an easy way to just move it over or do I repost it?

Comment: Honestly I haven't figured that out quite yet :D.

Comment: I'll go for simple repost method in that case then haha

Comment: The matrix thinking may be a wrong lead - most matrix operations are O(n^2), and if you need just n of these operations you are already in O(n^3) complexity.

Comment: That's true. I'm probably closer with the first process. Though in my head it requires `k` iterations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been cross-posted on the CS Stack Exchange.

Comment: If you read up in this comment thread the subject of being off-topic was previoisly mentioned.